# Return key/value from a dictionary less than or equal to a limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a program that gathers the values from a dictionary that are less than or equal to an entered value. The desired return will be a specific list that has the key,value in it. I am not sure how to begin or write this program.

For example:

```
dictionary1 = {'drill': 250.89, 'hammer': 25.99, 'press': 365.33}
Upper limit: 165
```

I will need to get a list back of all the contents of the dictionary and put them into a list, that have the value less than or equal to 165.
The returned list in this case should be: `list1 = ['hammer', 25.99]`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you say you want it to return a list but the desired result is either a list with a ```:``` instead of a ```,``` or a dictionary with ```[]``` instead of ```{}```. which is it?

Comment: My bad. It should be a list with []. I will have to have the tool and the number (which is the price) with it in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) to filter the key/value pairs:

```
upper_limit = 165
dictionary1 = {'drill': 250.89, 'hammer': 25.99, 'press': 365.33}

res = [(tool, value) for tool, value in dictionary1.items() if value < upper_limit]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[('hammer', 25.99)]
```